# MyAsana Error Unexcepted to connect

Tags: asana

I use API Asana in "MyAsana" to follow my Workspace (Project) in Asana.
The API is used in 10 smartphones from different people to follow the task of projects.

After 2 days, the API does not respond. All applications authorized in Asana do not respond.
I reset the API & it works in MyAsana. and today the same problem.
I have to do a reset and change the API in all phones.

Error is: UNEXEPTED ERROR WHILE CONNECTING WITH ASANA.THIS IS MOST LIKELY A PROBLEM WITH ASANA SERVER. Please try again later.

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 1):

Asana is currently having some problems with its service and has had to [temporarily shut down access to the API](https://twitter.com/asana/status/445597391991746561) while it addresses them. Follow `@asana` on twitter and you should get a tweet when access is restored.

Comment: Note, Asana restored access yesterday.